# Wrap a layout in a border

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to create a border that will go around a number of text boxes. I have been able to do this by defining a shape in XML and then using that shape as my background. Here is the defined shape.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#787878" /> 
  <padding android:left="7dp" android:top="7dp" 
           android:right="7dp" android:bottom="7dp" /> 
  <corners android:radius="4dp" />  
</shape>
```

and here is how I used it. Just on a textview at the moment.

> ```
> <TextView 
>   android:background="@drawable/my_border"
>     android:id="@+id/item_text"
>     android:layout_margin="5dip"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:textSize="16sp"
>     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>     android:text="@string/item_text"
>     android:textColor="#787878"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:textStyle="bold"/>
> ```

This actually draws the border as expected but the color within the board i.e. the background of the textview is black. I can't work out why this is. Any help of guesses to push me in the right direction are  appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `<solid android:color="#ffffff" />` to your `shape` definition.